# Is this an approach to create a read-only List in Java?

Tags: java, list

Thinking in java says:

> To create a read-only List from AbstractList, you must implements get() and size().

It confused me, the code is below:

```
 public class CountingIntegerList
extends AbstractList<Integer> {
  private int size;
  public CountingIntegerList(int size) {
    this.size = size < 0 ? 0 : size;
  }
  public Integer get(int index) {
    return Integer.valueOf(index);
  }
  public int size() { return size; }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List list = new CountingIntegerList(30);
  }
}
```

Is list a read-only List? Why?

Ok, the answer is yes since I extend `AbstractList` and it throw `UnsupportedOperationException` if `set` or `and` is called. If I want to get a unmodifiableList, `Collections.unmodifiableList()` is a good choice. But remember, both of them are not deeply immutable:

```
      List<StringBuilder> list = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append("hello");
      list.add(sb);
      System.out.println(list);
      list = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
      sb.append("world");
      System.out.println(list);
```

There is a `flyweight pattern` in `CountingIntegerList`. because everytime `get()` is called,it get caches from Integer, the source code of `valueOf()`:

```
   public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    final int offset = 128;
    if (i >= -128 && i <= 127) { // must cache 
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + offset];
    }
        return new Integer(i);
    }
```

Is is right?

Comment: This is one of possible approach.
Why? As you can see you can not add any element to this List..(Not through add method. ) I will suggest to have parameterrised constructor to take initial List. othirwise your unmodifiable List will never have any data

Comment: Which part is confusing you?

Comment: `your unmodifiable List will never have any data `?

Comment: Abstract collection classes provide the common functionality for the concrete classes that extend them. See the "Methods inherited from class java.util.AbstractList" in the ArrayList documentation for example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: @znlyj see in your list you are not adding any data via constructor. you are adding only size. and with oyu implementation its not possible to add new element as defualt add throws `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: yes, thank you, it seems that the list even not competent as a container.

Answer (score 5):

It's read-only (even immutable) because `add` will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` as will `remove`.

`AbstractList` handles all the work of creating iterators,
computing hashcodes and equality for you.  It's very helpful.
It's completely unnecessary to wrap in `unmodifiableList`.

Later you ask whether `AbstractList` is used mainly to create unmodifiable lists.  Actually it is used to create any kind of random-access list.  In my course in data structures, we use abstract classes such as this to save most of the work of implementing a list class.  Even the `Collection` interface has 13 methods, all but two of which are implements by `AbstractCollection`.

There is the related class `AbstractSequentialList` that helps create lists that are not random access (such as linked lists).

Comment: sorry, but I don't clearly understand of "It's completely unnecessary to wrap in unmodifiableList". Could you explain me?

Comment: The list you created doesn't have any way to be mutated.  The <code>unmodifiableList</code> wrapper will ensure that <code>add</code> and <code>remove</code> will throw exceptions, but since they do anyway, the wrapper is simply wasting space and time.

Comment: If you extend AbstractList then you need not wrap it with `unmodifiableList`. 
if you want to use your existing Collection class like ArrayList then you can make it unmodifiable by wrapping it with `unmodifiableList`.

Comment: @znlyj: your original list is just fine.  It is not the case (as some claim) that your list is empty.  It is an immutable list with `size` elements.

Comment: yes, it has 30 elements in fact, but i am wondering is the JVM allocate 30 reference elements memory space now? or it is just a seeming?

Comment: @znlyj No, your list takes up very little space.  Even if `size` is a million, it takes up the same size.  It's very efficient.  Notice how your `get` method creates each `Integer` object as requested.

Comment: It seems different from `ArrayList` which allocate 10 elements after `new` one? I mean, once `new CountingIntegerList`, it doesn't allocate  memory space at all to hold its elements.

Comment: @znlyj: that's right.  It doesn't need to hold its elements because it knows what they are and they never change.  It knows that i'th element is i.   `ArrayList` starts off with nulls, but people can change elements arbitrarily and thus `ArrayList` has to keep track of them.

Comment: I think it doesn't hold any elements not because ** it knows what they are and they never change** but there is no any container such as a array initialed, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

because `set` throws an UnsupportedOperationException, if not implemented. See [Api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#set%28int,%20E%29)

Comment: aha, maybe I should have an intimate knowledge of api first, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

you could wrap your List in an [UnmodifiableList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29)

```
List readOnlyList = Collections.unmodifiableList(yourList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the ArrayList into [Collections.unmodifiableList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29)

> Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list. This method allows
>   modules to provide users with "read-only" access to internal lists.
>   Query operations on the returned list "read through" to the specified
>   list, and attempts to modify the returned list, whether direct or via
>   its iterator, result in an UnsupportedOperationException. The returned
>   list will be serializable if the specified list is serializable.
>   Similarly, the returned list will implement RandomAccess if the
>   specified list does.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky a bit. The list can not change and/or the elements also? ;)

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Hello");
    List<StringBuilder> list = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
    list.add(builder);

    Collection<StringBuilder> canNotChange = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(list);
    builder.append(" World");
    System.out.println(canNotChange.iterator().next());
```

Comment: But you didn't change the list, isn't it? The list holds the reference elements as before.

Comment: @znlyj yup. that is the difference between immutable and deeply immutable. It depends on which suits your needs.

Comment: so my `CountingIntegerList` is not deeply immutable. `Collections.unmodifiableList` cant' create a deeply immutable list the same.

Comment: @znlyj yup. the thing is there is no way to create a deeply immutable list - it is up to you to do that. I would suggest as apposed from the answers you've got to create an ImmutableList from guava package. Much more flexible.